# Proper data type to store grid/interval-based attribute (e.g. interest rate on loan that varies according to credit rating)

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlite, relationship, datamodel

Suppose you have a table containing information related to different loans (call it "tbl_loans"):

```
CREATE TABLE loans (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  borrower_id TEXT NOT NULL,
  loan_name TEXT NOT NULL,
  maturity_date DATE,
  rating_id INT NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (borrower_id, loan_name, maturity_date)
```

Where rating_id corresponds to one of the following (in practice a loan's rating will change over time, but for these purposes assume it is constant):

```
id | rating
0  | A+
1  | A
2  | A-
3  | B+
...
6  | C+
...
```

And the interest rate on a particular loan is a function of the loan's rating (say *x*) and the following grid:

```
Rating Tier   | Interest Rate
A- <= x       | 1.0%
B  <= x < A-  | 1.5%
C+ <= x < B   | 2.0%
      x < C+  | 2.5%
```

How best would one store the grid for a specific loan, such that the interest rate could then be determined as a function of the loan's rating?

Any thoughts/suggestions/etc. appreciated.

Comment: So for example, you would have a separate table "interest_rates" along the lines of the following?

loan_id | rating_min_incl | rating_max_excl | interest_rate
1 | A- | null | 1%
1 | B | A- | 1.5%
1 | C+ | B | 2%
1 | null | C+ | 2.5%

Answer (score 0):

To build some intervals on a set the set should be at least [partially ordered](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set). But it is not in desired manner for letters with *optional* sign.

So first you need to order ratings:

> ```
> create table rating
> as
> select
>   column1 as id
>   , column2 as rating
>   , column3 as sort_order
>   /*Sort order should be the same as
>   order of ratings: higher rated should
>   have higher order to use comparison
>   of the same direction*/
> from (values
>   (1, 'A+', 100.0),
>   (2, 'A', 90.0),
>   (3, 'A-', 80.0),
>   (4, 'B+', 70.0),
>   (5, 'B', 60.0),
>   (6, 'B-', 50.0),
>   (7, 'C+', 40.0),
>   (8, 'C', 30.0)
> ) as t
> ```

Then you build `loan_rate`table as intervals designated by `from` (including) and `to` (not including) columns. For readability you may use "human readable" codes.

> ```
> create table loan_rate
> as
> select
>   column1 as rating_from
>   , column2 as rating_to
>   , column3 as rate
> from (values
>   ('A-', null, 0.01),
>   ('B', 'A-', 0.015),
>   ('C+', 'B', 0.02),
>   (null, 'C+', 0.025)
> )
> ```

Then you build a view, that will take all the intervals, decode them to ordering values, then put each rating into corresponding interval.

> ```
> create view v_get_loan_rate
> as
> select
>   r.rating
>   , lr.rate
>   , printf('%1.2f%', lr.rate*100) as rate_code
> from loan_rate as lr
>   /*Build from and to intervals
>   based on defined sort order*/
>   left join rating as r_f
>     on lr.rating_from = r_f.rating
>   left join rating as r_t
>     on lr.rating_to = r_t.rating
>   /*Use somewhat infinity for nulls:
>   negative infinity (-9999) for from
>   and positive infinity (9999) for to*/
>   left join rating as r
>     on r.sort_order >= coalesce(r_f.sort_order, -9999.0)
>       and r.sort_order < coalesce(r_t.sort_order, 9999.0)
> ```

And final test case:

> ```
> select *
> from v_get_loan_rate
> where rating = 'C'
> ```
>
> ```
> rating |  rate | rate_code
> :----- | ----: | :--------
> C      | 0.025 | 2.50%
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=9a92fe1fe2f2ddf42cf16064db72a6ae)*